Vue js and media recorder library Zoom in and out not working smooth in iPhone
I have a video recording feature using vue js and media recorder library. I have a recordButton component and recordScreen component. when user presses and hold the record button it starts recording a video. if user move the finger up it should zoom in and when move down it should zoom out. I have make the code with applyConstraints.
 <v-btn
    fab
    id="record-button"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    :class="{
        'touched': touched
    }"
    @mousedown="handleMouseDown"
    @mouseup="handleMouseUp"
    @touchstart="handleTouchStart"
    @touchend="handleTouchEnd"
    @touchmove="handleTouchMove"
/>

methods: {
    handleTouchStart(event) {
        this.touched = true
        if (this.disableVideo || this.useTimer) {
            return
        }

        this.touchStartY = event.touches[0].clientY;
        this.clearableInterval = setTimeout(() => {
                this.isVideoStart = true;
                this.$emit('videoStart')
            }, 1000
        )
    },
    handleTouchMove(event) {
        if (!this.isVideoStart) return;

        const currentY = event.touches[0].clientY;
        const deltaY = currentY - this.touchStartY;

        if (deltaY > 0) {
            // Move finger down: Zoom out
            this.zoomFactor = Math.max(this.minZoom, this.zoomFactor - 0.05);
            this.touchStartY = currentY;
        } else if (deltaY < 0) {
            // Move finger up: Zoom in
            this.zoomFactor = Math.min(this.maxZoom, this.zoomFactor + 0.05);
            this.touchStartY = currentY;
        }
        this.$emit('zoom-change', this.zoomFactor)
    },
}

In recordScreen I have this code for zoomChange method.
async handleZoomChange(zoomLevel) {
    await this.core.setZoom(zoomLevel);
},

it calls the storyCore.js file's setZoom method.
setZoom(newZoomLevel) {
        this.zoomLevel = newZoomLevel;
        if (this.stream && this.isZoomSupported) {
            this.stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
                track.applyConstraints({
                    advanced: [{ zoom: parseFloat(this.zoomLevel.toFixed(1)) }],
                });
            });
        }
}

This works fine without lag in android phone. But in iPhone idk somewhat it feels like it has lag issue and zoom in and zoom out works but in sudden not smooth
